# How does the numpy random normal function work?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics

What is `np.random.normal(32000,200000,3650)`? As far as I know the first value is the mean value, the second is the standard deviation and the last one is size. How can the deviation be `200000` when the mean is just `32000`?

And what is `np.random.seed(12345)`? And why is it used?

Comment: The first question is about statistics, not about `numpy` or even programming in general. The answer to your second answer can be obtained by reading the docs (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.seed.html). In short, it is used to make sure the random number generator will generate the same psuedo-random numbers every time (for testing, debugging etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python numpy.random.normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40979199/python-numpy-random-normal)

Answer (score 1):

the `np.random.seed` is the function that initialize the seed that generates random numbers. If it is specified, your program will always generate the same 'random' numbers.

The deviation is not related to the mean, it's just a number that indicates how much values are scattered. See the [Wikipedia article about standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation)

Comment: So do you mean that the numbers till 12345 will be repeated continuously? I still didn't understand this seed thing.

Comment: No, it's just a "reference" that defines how the number are generated. The generated numbers on the same execution will be different, but on different executions, the sequence of generated numbers will always be the same.